# Express app loads infinitely after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment

I have a very strange issue with my express application. I already deploy it on the server and everything worked fine, but after couple of hours, I tried to visit the website again and I couldn't because page started to load infinitely.

Here's my app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const session = require('express-session');
const apiAuth = require('./apiAuth');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
require('dotenv').config();

const basicAuth = new apiAuth().basicAuth;

const server = http.createServer(app);

/* Middleware */
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    // origin: "*"
    origin: [`${process.env.API_URL}:3000`, `${process.env.API_URL}:5000`]
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser({
    limit: "50mb"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: "50mb"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({
    limit: "50mb"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({
    limit: "50mb"
}));
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "secretcode",
        resave: true,
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { secure: false, expires: 1000 * 60 * 30 } /* Session expire in 30 minutes */
    })
);
app.use(flash());
const passport = require("passport");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/* Check if user is logged in middleware */
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.user) next();
    else res.redirect("/");
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

const urls = [
    'admin', 'panel', // ... other urls here
]

/* Routers */
const orderRouter = require('./routers/order');
const productRouter = require('./routers/products');
const addonRouter = require('./routers/addons');
const imageRouter = require("./routers/images");
const typesRouter  = require("./routers/types");
const stocksRouter = require('./routers/stocks');
const blogRouter = require('./routers/blog');
const newsletterRouter = require('./routers/newsletter');
const contentRouter = require('./routers/content');
const othersRouter = require('./routers/others');
const userRouter = require('./routers/user');
const formsRouter = require('./routers/forms');

app.use('/orders', orderRouter);
app.use('/products', productRouter);
app.use('/addons', addonRouter);
app.use('/types', typesRouter);
app.use('/stocks', stocksRouter);
app.use('/blog-api', blogRouter);
app.use('/newsletter-api', newsletterRouter);
app.use('/content', contentRouter);
app.use('/others', othersRouter.router);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/forms', formsRouter);
app.use("/image", imageRouter);

urls.forEach((item) => {
    app.get(`/${item}`, (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
    });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

I restarted my app and everything works fine again, but how could I find the issue that causes infinite loading?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, but can't reproduce it anymore. This may be related: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8196

Answer (score 0):

You are importing "morgan", but not using it in your code:

```
const morgan = require('morgan');

// --- //

app.use(morgan("dev"));
```

This should give you more logs that you can use and debug.

Comment: you can write it as a comment. don't write comment as an answer

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that. But will do as soon as I can. Thanks for the heads-up.